# change facebookDisplayName for swift app using firebase

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, firebase, authentication

When I originally started this project I called it "ChristinaApp" as a project starting name however I have now called the app "kai" I have updated this on facebook developer center and in the plist

```
 <key>FacebookAppID</key>
 <string>#############</string>
 <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
 <string>kai</string>   <---- I changed this to "kai"
```

When I try to log into the app I keep getting "ChristinaApp"

[image: How can I make this say "kai"]

Comment: Go To "Build Setting" and change "product name".

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to say, But you can't Modify  `app name` in `alert view` title directly because it is `system` generated alert.

If you want to change name alert then rename application. Title in display automatically got changed.

> You can change app name as below.

```
Go to Targets in Xcode
Get Info on your project's target (your current development name)
Search for Product Name under Packaging. Change the value of what you want the your new project name to be.
```